# Remote Desktop gateway for Linux

Tags: remote-desktop

I am trying to setup a Linux, for some kind like Remote Desktop proxy.

My network setup is something like this:

[image: network setup]

I drew only 3 sites and 3 servers to illustrate, but in fact, we have about 7 sites in a mesh, and about 2-3 servers per site. All of those sites are connected through L2TP/IPSEC tunnels through various media, from fiber, to 3G or EDGE connection.

Right now, I am using DDNS to connect to those remote locations, but this is getting tedious, since I have to maintain multiple DDNS, while I have multiple IP blocks at our data center unused. So I think I need something like an RD gateway, to proxy my requests to Server A, Server B, and Server C through one Static IP at Server A. Problem is, servers in A site are all Linux based. But some in site B and C are Windows based, especially that we are now using Windows 2016 Hyper-V Edition for our newest site.

Now, is there a way so I can Remote Desktop to ALL servers in ALL sites, using Server A as a proxy?

Thank you

Comment: You could configure one Linux server as proxy. As example proxy:3333 refers to ServerA:22, proxy:3334 refers to ServerB:3389 and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/144916/tools-for-remote-desktop-with-relay-feature

Comment: @BillThor I am looking for a linux app, text based, shell only server, that can relay multiple windows RD sessions to outside world.

Comment: @prd xrdp has a relay service.  I haven't tried it with Windows, but it has worked for Linux rdp sesions..

Answer (score 1):

You can find an open source remote desktop gateway service, that is equivalent to the proprietary Microsoft one, at https://github.com/bolkedebruin/rdpgw . You can configure your linux servers and windows servers without requiring them to be part of a domain. If your clients speak the remote desktop gateway protocol, you can even expose other services like VNC.